# Foreign language characters in iPhone SQLite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, special-characters

I'm creating an app for the iPhone that will hold Portuguese characters. When I query the database from within my app I get a null for the field that contains a special character.
Do I have to do something in special during the initial insertion of those records into the database?

thanks,

foreignerbr

Comment: by the way I'm running the script that populates the db tables from mac OSX's sqlite client.

Comment: Do you actually get a null character (`\0`), or do you mean that you get some sort of box or placeholder in the displayed string?